# The mouse pointer manipulating code

Tags: assembly, embedded

Suppose , I am in the year , let's say , in 1950's or 1960's . I don't have much facilities available in the programming languages available to me , like , PASCAL or FORTRAN OR ALGOL, and only recently "computer mouse " has been introduced and invented and only recently they are being supplied along with computer and when attached to one particular port in my computer I can see a "small arrow" on the computer screen (let it be even a CRT screen , hope you would allow relaxation for the lack of synchronization with actual chronology ) moving in accordance with the way I moved the mouse .

Now I wanted to have computer programs that could control the mouse pointer on screen. Let's say I want to write a computer program which would move the mouse pointer in the direction opposite to the direction in which I am moving the mouse or a computer program  to freeze the pointer on the mouse screen for few seconds or a computer program to change the shape of the mouse pointer when the mouse is moved to a specific part of the screen .

Given this requirement how will my language interact with the system to control the mouse pointer . Will the compiler of my language be changed to add few more instructions (or methods or functions ) which will yield machine code controlling the mouse pointers ?

Comment: In the 50ies and 60ies there was no Pascal, Algol was also not in the 50ies, less OOP with _methods_. They were also far from personal computers, mouse pointers and graphics as we know them now. Left all these errors apart: it is not clear what you are trying to ask. Maybe it helps if you can point us at the x86 instructions which handle mouse events. The instruction set documentation is freely available.

Comment: The mouse pointer is typically managed by the OS, it's the OS that is reacting to the mouse input events and drawing the pointer as appropriate. Thus to affect pointer motion, you just need to rewrite your mouse handler. In the unlikely case that you somehow have a strange hardware mouse cursor, it must support the functionality you want and there must be a way to ask for such services. You would use your normal methods that you already have for communicating with devices to achieve that, no change to compiler needed.

Comment: @Jester: That's wrong. Most OS donÄt care about mouse, that's left to the GUI. Only monolithic, broken OS put all together and mess up console applications with GUI stuff that way. Clean OS allow to run without GUI, e.g. for server applications and other head-less usages (e.g. embedded).

Comment: The point is, the mouse device only sends events that software then processes to eventually draw a pointer if and where appropriate. As such, to change that behavior you only need to change the software in between, and that software is already written using the normal available tools.

Comment: @Jester : But the OS itself is a computer program written in some language . My purpose was to understand how high-level slowly computer languages came up with instructions that enables an user to control some external physical device . So I wanted to retrace the steps .

Comment: @Olaf : Yup , there were no PASCAL  or ALGOL and hence I have mentioned about the poor sync with actual chronology . Could you please provide any link for x86 instructions for mouse events , I would be grateful to you.

Comment: @olaf : That's exactly what  I Wanted to know ,how were the languages changed to be add instructions which will be compiled into these mouse handling instructions .

Comment: They are not changed. For the actual low level access you might need special asm instructions such as `in` or `out` for x86, but those are architecture specific and not part of a portable language specification such as C. They are written in assembly. For memory mapped devices you don't even need those.

Comment: @AgniveshSingh: It was not me assuming such instructions existed, but you. So it is you to provide a reference supporting your claim. As I wrote: the documentation is available freely, just go ahead and read them.

Comment: Mouse, and other hardwares, have nothing to do with the language (unless it is a really poor language, which misses a way to interact with hardware, libraries or OS). Moreover, a "highlevel language" normally is fast enough to cope with a stupid mouse/pointer on the screen. On any computer, using a reasonable language, it is possible to manipulate the mouse (pointer) by implementing the functionality, or cooperating with some software (the OS? The GUI?) already present just for managing the mouse.

Comment: @linuxfan well.. none of that back in 1950-1985 ... just drawing proper bit-masked cursor took considerable amount of CPU back on ZX Spectrum... :D (lot more than 1/100 of single frame (50fps) ... the pixel editors often left cursor frozen while doing more complex algorithms like flood-fill (tenths of second) or scrolling through zoomed image). OP: most of the modern HW is now memory mapped, so the device manufacturer gives you documentation where you can read/write values in memory to affect device's behaviour. You can change memory content in any decent language ([asm, C and C++] = enough).

Comment: To quote directly from the Algol68 specification:

10.3.1.2. Channels

(aa) A "channel" corresponds to one or more physical devices (e.g., a card reader, a card punch or a line printer, or even to a set up in nuclear physics the results of which are collected by the computer) , or to a filestore maintained by the operating system.  ...

Two environment enquiries are provided for channels. These are:

• estab possible, which returns true if another file may be "established"  on the channel;

• standconv, which may be used to obtain the default "conversion key" for the channel

Answer (score 2):

You have it rather the wrong way around.  There is no direct hardware link between the mouse hardware and the mouse pointer - there must already software rendering the pointer in response to the mouse motion.  If you wanted the pointer to behave differently that would simply be *different* software rather than another software layer.

The language the software is written in is largely irrelevant, but system level code is most often written in a system level language.  In the era you are discussing that would generally be assembly code/machine code.  Any useful high level language of the time would have means to invoke machine code sub-routines to support extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose, I am in the year ... 1950's or 1960's.
> I don't have much facilities available in the programming languages.
> Now I wanted to have computer programs that could control the mouse pointer
>
> ... how will my language interact with the system to control the mouse?
> Will the compiler of my language be changed to add few more instructions ...?

**I think yes.**

In those years computers where more "rigid" than today; for example, you couldn't buy a computer from a supplier and attach to it a hard disk from another supplier. Programming languages supplied for a computer followed more or less the same approach; in few words, a computer was a "unique piece" of hardware and software, so everything needed was already present in "the unique piece".

I think this means that, if the 50's computers had a mouse, the programming language used on it would have special instructions to cope with it.

If we look at the BASIC language, for example, we can see that initially the PRINT instruction could print things in a "teletype" way. When teletypes where substituted by CRT terminals (those with video, maybe 25 lines of 80 columns of characters), new concepts like "cursor", "clear screen", "flashing characters" arose. Different ways to manage these new features were developed: from POKEing values to OS (or firmware) locations (low level), to using escape sequences (still used today), but finally the modern BASICs included, in the language, native support for them, like the LOCATE and CLS instructions, FLASH modifier, and similar things.

Taking a program written in BASIC for a machine X, and making it run on machine Y was not always trivial: the too many variants of BASIC and the many different machines around complicated the matter. Anyway, this was coherent with my first sentence: languages were tailored to a given hardware and were trying to offer functionalities for that hardware.

Things evolve, fortunately. Now you can buy a hard disk or a mouse from a supplier, and attach it to a computer from a different supplier. This is possible because of standardization. The same is for languages - nowadays nobody tries to develop a language to support specific features of a computer. Instead, languages (and operating systems) tend to implement kinds of *protocols* (or *standards*) that let them to inter-operate with other softwares (software libraries, drivers, OS services). Modern languages concentrate on well-defined syntaxes, models, concepts, and tend to be identical on every situation. Perhaps the first (used and successful) language made this way is C. In this language, I/O is not even specified by the language itself: you don't have a PRINT instruction in C; you have instead a standardized library, whose implementation varies from system to system, but the language does not.

So to conclude, modern languages **do not interact** with mouse or other hardware, they have features to let them to interact with other software. In the 50's years, instead, languages were planned differently than today.

PS: *if someone thinks that the English I used can be improved, feel free to edit*.